# Send bluetooth files without going through share contract?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I can enumerate the connected devices and also send a file from one device to another through the DataTransferManager (share contract), but would like to be able to specifically manage that step directly behind the scenes.  I want to do this to eliminate a step and make the user experience more efficient in regards to sending/receiving files in my app.  Basically the user would only need to pick the file that they want to send and the app would take care of everything else.  If it's possible to use the share contract without the ui then that would work as well.  All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't use Share contract without the share UI in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps. To support the Share contract, launching the share UI is necessary. And in UWP apps, we usually call [DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.showshareui) to programmatically launch the user interface. We can also launch the Share user interface through Share charm (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>).

If you do not want the UI, you can take advantage of [Bluetooth RFCOMM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm). This doc has example code: [Send a file as a client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm#send-a-file-as-a-client).

Comment: Thanks Jay!  I think the share contract will work and I have it functional, but may look into the RFComm.